# How can I "type on path" in Cinema4d like I can do in (eg) Illustrator?

Tags: 3d, typesetting, path, cinema4d

We all know you can *"type on path"* in Adobe's Illustrator like this:

[image: illustrator example]

Now, I would like to do the same in Maxon's Cinema 4D but after checking the documents and several search engines, I still haven't found the magic bullet to do that.

[image: cinema4d example]

How can I "type on path" in Cinema4d like I can do in (eg) Illustrator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two tutorials using a spline as a rail guide:

Creative Cows: Text on spiral spine-http://forums.creativecow.net/thread/19/874454

C4DCafe: Text along non-banking helix-http://www.c4dcafe.com/ipb/topic/61320-text-along-non-banking-helix-spilin/

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Easy, assuming you have Illustrator handy.

1. Create what you're after in Illustrator.
2. Select the text and convert it to outlines (from memory, it's Type > Create Outlines, or command-shift-O).
3. Export the document into a format Cinema 4D can read. SVG should do the trick.

You're done!

Comment: I know about that workaround. When I use it, I use the *Illustrator3* as the export format to import it into C4D. But doing it that way, I can't edit/modify the text in Cinema4D. And I don't always have Illustrator handy. That's why I'm looking for a *"native"* way to do it in C4D directly without the need of any other software. But don't get me wrong - even when I can't use it, I appreciate your answer.